# Changing CSS Display property with Javascript but keeps disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element in my page which I want to make visible only upon the click of a button. This works as expected, except the div promptly disappears again and I cannot get it to remain visible.

```js
    function btnAddItem_Click() {
            document.getElementById("add-item-popup").style.display = "block"
        }
```

```css
    .add-item-popup {
        width: 400px;
        height: 550px;
        display: none;
        background-color: #ededed;
        position: fixed;
        right: 40%;
        top: 20%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="add-item-popup" id="add-item-popup">
        //Contains a form
    </div>





    <button onclick="btnAddItem_Click()">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: can you please tell the results

Comment: @AhmedsaysReinstateMonica The div appears as expected for a second and then disappears again

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: as I have edited your question this is not happening. Check other libraies

Comment: @Brandon Holz you can use jquery `slideToggle()` function.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to show why it would disappear - https://jsfiddle.net/ufd0n3c6/, you must have other code also running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a reasonable assumption but an assumption nonetheless with this solution.  The assumption is your `<button>` tag with your `onclick` handler is *inside* of another form. If so, replace this line here:

`<button onclick="btnAddItem_Click()">Add Item</button>`

To become this code:

`<button type="button" onclick="btnAddItem_Click()">Add Item</button>`

Explanation: When button is inside a form without `type="button"` specified, it will submit the form, and in your case, reload the page where the css then of course is anew. Thus you only see a "blip" of the displayed div.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code your issue is resolved.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```